# Mod Rewrite a url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

What is the best way to redirect 
`product.php?product=[variable-id]` to `item/[variable-id]`.

For example: `product.php?product=45` to `item/45`

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/product\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/item/%1.php [L,R=301]
```

but this not working...

Comment: are you using framework or procedural php approach ?

Comment: Use `header('Location: https://www.example.com/blahblah/' . $variable);`

Comment: No framework. Yes, i'm using a procedural php approach.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need code that works inside .htaccess. I tried something like this:  RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/product\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/item/%1.php [L,R=301] but this not working....

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Do you literally only want to redirect from `product.php?product=45` to `item/45`? Does your application already know how to route a URL of the form `item/45`?

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in the .htaccess file of the root directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /product\.php\?product=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ /item/%1? [R,L]
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)?$ /product.php?product=$1 [NC,L]
```

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` (permanent redirect).

Answer (score 1):

This is "*the best way*"<sup>[*]</sup> to redirect `product.php?product=[variable-id]` to `item/[variable-id]`, where `product` is always the first URL parameter, `[variable-id]` must exist and consists only of the digits 0-9.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^product\.php$ /item/%1 [R=302,L]
```

If this is intended to be a permanent redirect then change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only once you have confirmed everything is working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser, so clear your browser cache before testing.

<sup><sup>[*]</sup> Debatable - based on the limited information in the question.</sup>